# tagged and named tagged nics on EL6 not show the correct name

Tags: networking, vlan, rhel-6

I added some VLANS (100 and 200) to my trunk connected to eth0.
In the ifcfg-eth0.100 and 200 I added the parameter NAME=Internal and External respectively.
When the OS is starting up and or when I restart the network, I correctly see the name I chose when bringing the interfaces up.

If I run "ip a" or "ifcfg", it doesn't show the correct name but "eth0.100@eth0" and the final user wants to see the name I typed in the parameter.

Any idea why? and how to fix that?

Thanks